# CertificateIsInvalid when trying to navigate to site with self signed certificate with WebView (Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls)

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

I want to display a site with a self signed certificate in WebView (Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls). I am using WPF on .net core 3.

I have the cert in my root store.

When I try to navigate to the site with WebView, it gives me the WebErrorStatus
`CertificateIsInvalid`.

When I open the site in Edge and view the certificate information, it says "Valid Certificate".

How can I get the site to render in WebView?